# What is the timing of information assimilation within a human brain?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, brain, dreaming

A little background: I'm an avid dreamer and have great dream recall, sometimes up to 5-7 per night.

In my experience, I can sometimes trace some elements of the dream to an event that occured within a 1-3 day window prior to the dream.

I've done similar experiments with the process of idea generation, where an idea that I have can be traced to experiences from the previous 1-3 days.

This makes me interested if there have been some kind of studies on how rapidly the brain absorbs and assimilates information from short term memory over to the long term memory. **Has there been any studies on how long the brain keeps information before discarding or processing/assimilating it into dreams or new ideas?**

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) where there are already questions [similar to it](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/833/29)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is belongs in  CogSci.SE

Comment: Try googling on "consciousness lag". I cannot cite any sources, but I have heard many times that working of consciousness happens in waves, and it is normal, when having some strong experience, for it to be experinced for some time, then come down, then rise again, say, in +1 minute, in +5 minutes, in +20 minutes, in +1 hour, in +1 day, in +3 days and so on... in some sense, the work of consciousness is similar to water surface with waves.. you can read much about that in eastern philosophy, and it plays well with electromagnetic nature of waves in the nervous system.